# Example of "lowerbound" and "upperbound" in the UCI protocol

Tags: engines, uci

I am having trouble understanding how "upperbound` and "lowerbound" come into play in the UCI protocol.

The spec says:

> - lowerbound: the score is just a lower bound.
> - upperbound: the score is just an upper bound.

For example, I see Stockfish using it like this.

```
info depth 22 seldepth 27 multipv 1 score cp 27 upperbound nodes 2567224
```

I kind of understand that it is related to the "cp." But I don't really know how. Could someone help me clarify this? It would be best if you used an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a type of info which an engine can produce *during* the search, mainly targeted at developers. It means that at that depth stockfish (believes to) have established, that the score it at least 27 centipawns. [Stockfish](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Stockfish) uses some variation of [aspiration search](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Aspiration_Windows) and this variant can produce such intermediate results. An engine like [Leela Zero](https://lczero.org/) uses a different algorithm and therefore never bother the users with such infos.

If you are only interested in chess contents, you can completely ignore that output.

Answer (score 0):

Another search algorithm that produces lower and upper bounds is [MTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTD(f)). It is basically a binary search that narrows in on the true value.